# Prove that the holomorphic function defined by a certain sum can't be extended to a neighborhood of 1

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, holomorphic-functions, analytic-continuation

**Problem:**
Let
$$f(z) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}z^{2^n}$$
noting that the sum has radius of convergence 1.  Prove that there exists no neighbourhood *U* of 1 and holomorphic function *g*:$U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that *f = g* on $U\cap\mathbb{D}$.

**Attempts**: I have only vague ideas so far.  My original idea was to use the uniqueness of power series and the fact that $g$ would be analytic at 1 to derive a contradiction of the fact that the radius of convergence of $f$ is 1.  Help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'm missing something: The function $f$ *is* holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{D}$, so there *is* such a function $g$ (namely $f$ itself) for any $U$. Is there an assumption missing?

Comment: Nope, I'm missing something.  I forgot to mention that g is holomorphic on $U$.  Corrected.

Comment: the derivative diverges when approaching $z = e^{2i\pi a 2^{-k}}$ with $a,k \in \mathbb{N}$  @T.Bongers

Comment: @user1952009 Indeed, and an unbounded derivative breaks it all (but the original version asked a different question).

Comment: @T.Bongers well it asked to extend analytically $f(z)$ beyond $|z| < 1$

Comment: @user1952009 The original version did not. It asked for an analytic function coinciding with $f$ on $U \cap \mathbb{D}$, which isn't terribly interesting.

Answer (score 4):

$f$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb D$, so we have the expansion for $f'$,
$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{2^n}{n^4} x^{2^n-1}$$
$f'$ has a non-removable singularity at $x=1$ because
$$\lim_{\substack{x→ 1^- \\[0.1em] x∈ \Bbb R}}f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{2^n}{n^4} = ∞$$ so it cannot be extended to a holomorphic function on a neighbourhood including $1$, which means neither can $f$.

Comment: Ah.  This makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: That the convergence of the series for $f'$ breaks down at $z=1$ does not prove anything. Consider the following example:  The convergence of the series for $g(z):={1\over 1+z^2}$ breaks down at $z=1$, but the function $g$ lives happily around there.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter right, but in this case $f'(x) \xrightarrow[\Bbb R \ni x \to 1^-]{}  ∞ $. I'll edit to make it clearer.